# Blocking Flash Player from router to prevent user from wasting bandwith

Tags: networking, router, video, flash, bandwidth

There is one user on the network which is always watching videos with Flash Player and eating bandwith and I cannot get the user to disable Flash Player but instead can I block it using my router? I don't want to completely block the user but prevent the user from watching videos with Flash Player (HTML5 isn't supported on that user's PC)

How can I do this ? My router is a PROLiNK H5004N

Answer (score 0):

The prolink does not come with a port blocking option and can not control data flow based on type (Flash). This wouldn't help you anyway, because Flash will fall back to port 80 if it can't connect. If you block port 80, you block web access. So no, natively you can not do it. The next question is, what about DD-WRT or tomato? No, you can not install either one on your router. So what are your options. Put an entry in their local hosts file (on their computer) that routes requests for the IP's (or URI's) they access that have flash content, to 127.0.0.1. Then your network will not be effected at all.

You can google directions for this specific to their OS.

Comment: I can't touch that PC.And I also don't need Flash Player since I rarely watch videos and even then they are HTML5 (because I have a modern browser) and I have Flash disabled

Comment: Then the answer is, you have no way to do this with what is currently available.  What you can do is get a Raspberry Pi, and set it up as a firewall, then place it between his computer and the router. Problem with this is, all he has to do is remove it. Those are your choices based on what you have available.